# gitLab update : curl returns ssl error 35

Tags: ssl, curl, gitlab

I am trying to update my gitLab installation from 7.7.2.
When I am running the following command nothing downloads.

`curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`

And I get this error:

```
0* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to packages.gitlab.com:443
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:00 --:--:--
0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to packages.gitlab.com:44
3
curl is unable to connect to packagecloud.io over TLS when running:
    curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/co
nfig_file.list?os=Ubuntu&dist=trusty&name=git.curuba2.fr&source=script
This is usually due to one of two things:

 1.) Missing CA root certificates (make sure the ca-certificates package is i
nstalled)
 2.) An old version of libssl. Try upgrading libssl on your system to a more
recent version
```

My ubuntu Trusty is up to date, I have ca-certificates installed and I also did update-ca-certificates.

No idea what's wrong. I need to migrate my server. I installed it properly on the new one but I fail updating the old one...

[EDIT]
I also tried with -k with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem trying to install the runner via a non-https proxy.
I tried using `-x [proxy] --insecure` in the command but it still failed.
I decided to look at the script itself and realised the issue is with the curl calls inside the script.
I update the calls I could find in a local copy of `script.deb.sh` to include `-x [proxy] --insecure` then just executed that using `sudo ./script.deb.sh` and it worked.

Comment: 2021, still here, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

That's more a wrkaround than an answer.
I finally downgraded my future server to 7.7.2, restored there my backup and upgraded back to 7.12.0.

Here are the commands I ran on the future server:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl stop unicorn
sudo gitlab-ctl stop sidekiq
wget https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu-14.04/gitlab_7.7.2-omnibus.5.4.2.ci-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -r gitlab-ce
sudo dpkg -i git*.deb
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
cd /var/opt/gitlab/backups/ # This is where backups should be located
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1435537802
sudo gitlab-ctl start unicorn
sudo gitlab-ctl start sidekiq
sudo gitlab-ctl status
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

Comment: sorry to say, but I think downgrading is a big problem from a security point of view, better the other alternative, this is also not a solution, just another workaround that might create a bigger problem...
Also, not always doable in a serious production environment.

Comment: I did this work on a staging environement and then migrated the final upgraded release.